# Does death remove Recurring Dreams progress?

Tags: fallen-london

If I die from Wounds in [Echo Bazaar](http://echobazaar.failbettergames.com/), would it reset my Recurring Dreams progress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just died and recovered; my dream progress is intact.